# Gradle ShadowJar : include recursively dependency

Tags: gradle, shadowjar

I use `shadowJar` to include my dependencies in my JAR

```
shadowJar {
  archiveClassifier = ""
  dependencies {
    include(dependency("org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.4.2.201908231537-r"))
    include(dependency("net.dv8tion:JDA:4.1.1_140"))
  }
}
```

the problem is that it didn't add all the dependancie tree of my dependancies and I don't know why.

Have someone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a configuration for that dependencies and include it into a shadow JAR:

```
configurations {
    extras
}

dependencies {
    extras "org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.4.2.201908231537-r"
    extras "net.dv8tion:JDA:4.1.1_140"
}

shadowJar {
  configurations = [project.configurations.compile + project.configurations.extras]
}
```